# Suggest opensource BPM engine for low-latency service-task

Tags: jbpm, activiti, business-process-management, bpmn, camunda

- Currently I developed in-house workflow engine for **non-human** tasks.
- In average,my flow have about 20 service-task support about 100 TPS per 1 host.   ( A 20 cores intel x86 server ). Latency between task in **near zero.**
- I'm consider the opensource BPM engine to replace mine to get more performance , GUI design tool ,GUI for monitoring.
- I have no experience in BPM, I have researched some of them, I think they focus on human-task. So I about **how latency** between each service-task.
- Could you give suggestion which one is suitable with my requirement?

Comment: You mention you have a flow with 20 service-task each and you run 100 TPS. Does that mean you run 5 flows per second or 100 flows each with 20 tasks? I just moved from jbpm to activiti for performance reasons and i am willing to discuss a bit..

Answer (score 1):

Consider Eclipse Stardust:
https://www.eclipse.org/stardust/

If you configure transient processes (or async writing of audit data) then very low latency is possible.(see http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.stardust.docs.dev%2Fhtml%2Fconcepts%2Faudit-trail%2Ftransient-procs.html&cp=72_4_6_1)

We did benchmarks including deferred writing of audit data with up to 20.000 messages per second. The bottleneck at this point was still the Oracle RAC writing the audit data. (see examples environments: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Stardust/Knowledge_Base/Infrastructure_System_Administration_Maintenance/Hardware_And_Sizing)

Also see:
Knowledgebase: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Stardust/Knowledge_Base